# jQuery - Hide and Show a div

Tags: jquery, css, forms, webforms, styling

On this page: http://www.ubhape2.com/formhelp.html

I have 3 file uploads. I have it set now that when you click "Add Another File" it shows the next file upload. Works great. I want to tweak it a touch. When you click Add Another File the next one shows and the "Add Another File" Image goes away. The file input itself is still there only the add button changes to a display:none.  I can't get this to work right. Either the entire file input hides or nothing hides.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: assign unique `ids` to every `img` and when clicked fade it away ...

Comment: Hi girl! Glad to see your site improving each day. Could you post the relevant HTML and javascript you're using. PS: I can't reproduce the behaviour you mention

Comment: Thank you so very much for kudos! I got it fixed using the method below. (from Igor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your `showfilehide` functions in that way:

```
function showfilehideN()
{
    document.getElementById('addfileN').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('filehideN').style.display='block';
}
```

N is for number of function (`showfilehide1` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

give different ids for each a tag and on a tag click hide the corresponding a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give your image button a class name . Then you can do something like the generic example below

```
var x = 'Test<img class="upload" src="http://www.ubhape2.com/images/Icons/addfile.png" /><br>';
$('.upload').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('body').append(x);
})
```

Modify as you see fit so it works for your site.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Qgq8B/

Answer (score 0):

USe only one button to show/hide the other two fileUploads,

JavaScript section,

```
             function ShowNextFileUpload()
             {
                var File2=document.getElementById('<%=File2.ClientID%>');
                var File3=document.getElementById('<%=File3.ClientID%>'); 

                if(File2.style.display=="none")
                {
                   File2.style.display="block";
                } 
                else
                {
                   File3.style.display="block";
                }
             }
```

Aspx section,

```
         <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" />
         <asp:FileUpload ID="File2" runat="server" style="display:none"/>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="File3" runat="server" style="display:none"/>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowNextFileUpload()">Add Another</asp:LinkButton>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
<input type="button" id="upldBtn" value="Add file" onclick="loadNext();"
 crntNumber="1" />
<div id="divUpld1" style="display:block;"></div>
<div id="divUpld2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="divUpld3" style="display:none;"></div>
```

now goes the script

```
<script type="test/javasript">
function loadNext(){
    var crntNumber = $('#upldBtn').attr("crntNumber");
    $("divUpld"+crntNumber).fadeOut(200, function(){
        $("divUpld"+crntNumber).css("display", "none");
        crntNumber++;
        $("divUpld"+crntNumber).fadeIn(200, function(){
              $("divUpld"+crntNumber).css("display", "block");
        });
        $('#upldBtn').attr("crntNumber", crntNumber);
    });
}
</script>
```

hope it helps.